# Regex that works with BaseSpider causes error with CrawlSpider

Tags: python, regex, json, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have the following code containing a regex on a Javascript item called Datastore.prime that i know definitely existed on a static page I was experimenting with using a BaseSpider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
import time
import re
import json


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal4"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com"]
    download_delay = 1

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/Teams',)), follow=True, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):


        playerdata = re.search(re.escape("DataStore.prime('stage-player-stat', defaultTeamPlayerStatsConfigParams.defaultParams , ") \
                     + '(\[.*\])' + re.escape(");"), response.body).group(1)

        for player in json.loads(playerdata):
            print player['FirstName'], player['LastName'], player['TeamName'], player['PositionText'], player['PositionLong'] \
            , player['Age'] \
            , player['Height'], player['Weight'], player['GameStarted'], player['SubOn'], player['SubOff'] \
            , player['Goals'], player['OwnGoals'], player['Assists'], player['Yellow'], player['SecondYellow'], player['Red'] \
            , player['TotalShots'] \
            , player['ShotsOnTarget'], player['ShotsBlocked'], player['TotalPasses'], player['AccuratePasses'], player['KeyPasses'] \
            , player['TotalLongBalls'], player['AccurateLongBalls'], player['TotalThroughBalls'], player['AccurateThroughBalls'] \
            , player['AerialWon'], player['AerialLost'], player['TotalTackles'], player['Interceptions'], player['Fouls'] \
            , player['Offsides'], player['OffsidesWon'], player['TotalClearances'], player['WasDribbled'], player['Dribbles'] \
            , player['WasFouled'] \
            , player['Dispossesed'], player['Turnovers'], player['TotalCrosses'], player['AccurateCrosses'] \

execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal4'])
```

When this regex is used as part of a CrawlSpider as in the above example the code instead throws up the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
     self.runUntilCurrent()
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
     call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 383, in callback
     self._startRunCallbacks(result)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 491, in _startRunCallbacks
     self._runCallbacks()
 --- <exception caught here> ---
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 578, in _runCallbacks
     current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
   File "c:\Python27\missing\missing\spiders\mrcrawl2.py", line 26, in parse
     + '(\[.*\])' + re.escape(");"), response.body).group(1)
 exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

The static page where I know this example worked can be found here:

http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/705/Archive/Israel-Maccabi-Haifa
I'm assuming that the above error is caused if Scrapy attempts to parse a page where no instance of DateStore.prime is encountered. Could someone please advise me whether:

1) This assumption is correct
2) How I can get around this problem. I have tried using 'try:' and 'except:' instances, however I'm not sure how I would code something along the lines of 'if error crawl next page'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from chaining together method calls `search` and `group`. If `search` returns `None`, then `None.group` raises the `AttributeError`.

Instead, split up the two method calls and use `if match is not None`. For example:

```
def parse_item(self, response):

    match = re.search(re.escape("DataStore.prime('stage-player-stat', defaultTeamPlayerStatsConfigParams.defaultParams , ") \
                 + '(\[.*\])' + re.escape(");"), response.body)
    if match is not None:
        playerdata = match.group(1)

        for player in json.loads(playerdata):
            ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot that worked with perfectly. only tweak is the function needs to be called 'parse_item' rather than 'parse' as the crawl spider uses a function of it's own called 'parse'. that was my typo above.